# Flutter how to make search bar with json model

Tags: flutter, searchbar

The source codes in link below is a search bar function without json model, if i wanted to change the items with json model, how to do so? Does anyone have any idea

[Click here to look at the source codes](https://karthikponnam.medium.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685)

Look at his final code at the end.

Comment: Please share json Model here.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_autocomplete_demo/country_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_autocomplete_demo/splash_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Splash(),
    );
  }
}


const List<Country> countryOptions = <Country>[
  Country(name: 'Africa', size: 30370000),
  Country(name: 'Asia', size: 44579000),
  Country(name: 'Australia', size: 8600000),
  Country(name: 'Bulgaria', size: 110879),
  Country(name: 'Canada', size: 9984670),
  Country(name: 'Denmark', size: 42916),
  Country(name: 'Europe', size: 10180000),
  Country(name: 'India', size: 3287263),
  Country(name: 'North America', size: 24709000),
  Country(name: 'South America', size: 17840000),
];

class AutoCompleteDemo extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AutoCompleteDemoState();
}

class _AutoCompleteDemoState extends State<AutoCompleteDemo> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title:Text('Flutter AutoComplete Demo'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Autocomplete<Country>(
          optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
            return countryOptions
                .where((Country county) => county.name.toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase())
            )
                .toList();
          },
          displayStringForOption: (Country option) => option.name,
          fieldViewBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
              FocusNode fieldFocusNode,
              VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted
              ) {
            return TextField(
              controller: fieldTextEditingController,
              focusNode: fieldFocusNode,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            );
          },
          onSelected: (Country selection) {
            print('Selected: ${selection.name}');
          },
          optionsViewBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              AutocompleteOnSelected<Country> onSelected,
              Iterable<Country> options
              ) {
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Material(
                child: Container(
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    itemCount: options.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final Country option = options.elementAt(index);

                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          onSelected(option);
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(option.name, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for more check [here](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-autocomplete-widget-in-flutter-70d3478bacc4)